# Explicit construction of irreducible unitary connections

Tags: riemann-surfaces, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

On a Riemann surface irreducible unitary connections on complex vector bundles of rank $n\geq 2$ are uniquley determined by their underlying holomorphic structure $\frac{1}{2}(\nabla+i*\nabla)$, where $*$ is the adjoint of the complex structure $J$ of the Riemann surface. This holomorphic structure is stable.

Are there any special examples, where this correspondence is made more explicit?

Comment: Surely you mean unitary connections on complex vector bundles on a complex manifold, for otherwise there is no underlying holomorphic structure.  Since gauge theory is not only studied on complex manifolds, then could I ask you to please edit your question and state clearly your assumptions?  Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for editing the question!


Comment: You have been right, I should have ask my question more carefully. Thanks for your comments.